# Select MAX value from other table, if any

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

What i want to achieve is really really basic, and I found a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078280/last-record-of-join-table), but i can't make it work with MS SQL Compact which i'm using.

Lets say i have these tables:

```
User                    Comments
ID   | Name             UserID | Comment           | Posted
-----+-------------     -------+-------------------+----------
0    | Adam             1      | Whatever 1        | 2014-01-01
1    | Beth             1      | whatever 2        | 2014-01-02
2    | Chris            0      | Whatever 3        | 2014-01-02
3    | David            3      | Whatever 4        | 2014-01-04
```

What i want is to get all users and present their latest comment, if any. If no comment it should just be null. That is, i want this result:

```
Name  | Comment          | Posted
------+------------------+-----------
David | Whatever 4       | 2014-01-04
Beth  | Whatever 2       | 2014-01-02
Adam  | Whatever 3       | 2014-01-02
Chris | NULL             | NULL
```

What i have, so far, is something like this code (simplified for this example):

```
SELECT u.Name AS Name, c.Comment AS Comment, c.Posted AS Posted
FROM User AS u
INNER JOIN Comments AS c ON u.ID = c.UserID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT UserID, MAX(Posted) AS Posted FROM Comments AS c2 GROUP BY UserID
) AS c2 ON c2.Posted = c.Posted ORDER BY Posted DESC
```

This somehow works, but in my sharp example I have 100 users and distinct UserID:s in Comments are 93 posts. But I only get 84 rows, when I should have 100 rows with 7 NULL rows? 
So, my questions are:

1) What's wrong in my query

2) How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is along the right track, but you need `left join` instead of `inner join` and to rearrange the join order:

```
SELECT u.Name AS Name, c.Comment AS Comment, c.Posted AS Posted
FROM User u LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT UserID, MAX(Posted) AS Posted
      FROM Comments c2
      GROUP BY UserID
     ) c2
     ON u.ID = c2.UserID LEFT JOIN
     Comments c
     ON c2.Posted = c.Posted
ORDER BY Posted DESC;
```

Your query only returns users that have at least one comment, so you it misses users with no comments.

Comment: Well, I've tried turning them all directions but with the wrong number of results. ;) that gave the same number of posts.

Comment: late edit; i missed that you put LEFT on both, and that gave me hundreds of rows. But yea, some how my query is not really right since it does not give me all 100 users.

Comment: @gubbfett . . . I can see how that would happen.  The `join`s need to be in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as what Gordon Linoff said except from the last left join.

```
    SELECT u.Name AS Name, c2.Posted AS Posted,c.Comment
     FROM [User] u LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT UserID, MAX(Posted) AS Posted
      FROM Comments c2
      GROUP BY UserID
     ) c2
     ON u.ID = c2.UserID LEFT JOIN
     Comments c on c2.Posted=c.Posted AND c2.UserId=c.UserId
```